# Cant login as admin after migration in OSClass 3.3.2

Tags: osclass

after migrating the website to a bigger host , I cant login to the admin control panel. I tracked the code and I saw in login.php it passes all error messages for control (password field is not empty, verify password, etc.), and it reachs the line
$this->redirectTo( $url_redirect ); with the right url to redirect (/oc-admin/index.php) but somehow after that line or file, the browser is redirect to oc-admin/index.php?page=login which is not right because it's the login page. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to solve it, I had to add

> session_save_path ( ABS_PATH . 'oc-content/uploads/' );

to the config.php file

Comment: Thank you so much...it is working fine now ! you saved my day !